# Perl command line one-liner to find regular expression matches that span multiple lines?

Tags: perl

For example, I have a file `foo.txt` that contains

```
abc
bcc
ccc
baa
```

and I want to return the indexes of all instances of "c\nb" (in this case, the string is found at starting at the third and eleventh characters of the file). What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure the file is small enough to fit comfortably into memory, you can just slurp it into a variable and apply a regex to it:

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $-[0], "\n" while /c\nb/g' foo.txt
```

Otherwise:

```
$ perl -ne 'print $n - 2, "\n" if /^b/ && $last =~ /c$/; $last = $_; $n += length' foo.txt
```

Note that these solutions depend on the input file containing only ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $s = 'abc
bcc
ccc
baa';

while ($s =~ /c\nb/mg ) {
  print pos($s), "\n"
}
```

this will output 5, 13 (the `pos` function returns the index of the end of the match, but you should be able to compensate for that).

Comment: Yes, Perl allows you to [run complete programs from the command-line](http://p3rl.org/run#%2A-e%2A-_commandline_).

Comment: @jonderry, try `perl -e 'my $s; while (<>) {$s .= $_} while ($s =~ /c\nb/mg ) { print pos($s) - 2, "\n" }' < foo.txt` (outputs 3 and 11, i did the adjustment for you).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a decent regex solution to this, but I'll fall back on the older [`index`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#index) function:

```
$_ = q[abc
bcc
ccc
baa];

my $z; print $z++,"\n" while 0<=($z=index($_,"c\nb",$z));
```

---

```
2
10
```